# Probability Question on PDF

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A class of the first year B.Tech students is composed of four batches A,B,C and D, each consisting of 30 students. It is found that the sessional marks of students in Engineering Drawing in batch C have mean 6.6 and deviation 2.3. The mean and standard deviation of the marks for the entire class are 5.5 and 4.2 respectively. It is decided by the course instructor to normalized the marks of the students of all batches to have the same mean and standard deviation as that of the entire class. Due to this, the marks of a student in batch C are changed from 8.5 to ----__________________________________________________________
How to solve such question? I know basic stuff like standard deviation, mean but unable to understand which formula applied here

Comment: I have no clue for this question. I got it in a test series question. I am getting totally dumb with this question. Please help me out, how to proceed

Comment: I've never come across a question like this before but I would think it would be something like converting the 8.5 to a z score about a mean of 6.6 which would be 1.9/2.3 and then adjusting it to the same z score about a mean of 5.5 which would be 5.5 + 1.9/2.3*4.2 = 8.97. Intuitively this seems about right, that is, adjusting a higher than average score to a slightly lower mean but with a significantly larger standard deviation quite reasonably increases the score.